# IE 7/8 javascript sorting error "Number Expected"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling

I'm having JSON object

```
var x=[{@Name:'test 1',@Sort:'1',@Status:'yes'},
       {@Name:'test 2',@Sort:'5',@Status:'yes'},
       {@Name:'test 3',@Sort:'4',@Status:'no'},
       {@Name:'test 5',@Sort:'2',@Status:'no'}]
```

I'm trying to sort the obj by @Sort,@Name and @Status.

```
    var orderBy="@Sort";
    x.sort(_sortObj(orderBy));

    function _sortObj(orderBy){
        return function(a,b){
           return (a[orderBy]<b[orderBy])?1:0....etc
        }
    }
```

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome...

But throws error in IE 7/8 as "number expected"
on line

```
  x.sort(_sortObj(orderBy));
```

I'm not sure what's going on and it will be great if anyone sort this out properly.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: @jbabey I don't think it's necessarily a duplicate. The algorithm is correct, but it's throwing an exception in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solved this issue using the below Sorting plugin,

http://www.thomasfrank.se/downloadableJS/objSort.js

Thanks guys for helping me around

Answer (score 1):

That is not a JSON object. The property names and values MUST be enclosed in "double quotes".

This is probably the reason for the error in older IE, it doesn't understand the `@` being there.

Comment: Its actually an 3rd party API ... i donno why those with @ but i have to go with it

Comment: can u guide to get thro this double quotes

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kolink's answer, IE might not be coercing your string-y numbers into actual numeric objects for the `<` comparison. You can perform that coercion yourself by multiplying by 1:

```
return (a[orderBy]*1 < b[orderBy]*1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: How are you receiving this JSON from your API? As a string? If so, you can probably perform a regular expression replacement of the malformed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same issue with you, and seems like it's an IE issue, maybe you can try this:

```
var orderBy="@Sort";
x.sort(_sortObj(orderBy));

function _sortObj(orderBy){
    return function(a,b){
       var aa = a,bb = b;
       return (aa[orderBy]<bb[orderBy])?1:0....etc
    }
}
```

you can find some help from here:http://www.zachleat.com/web/array-sort/comment-page-1/#comment-3941